# Match an id in existing xml and output matched parts of the xml as new xml

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

Hello I have an xml feed which has many products and each product can have mutiple skus. I'm trying to loop over that xml and then if I find a match for the EAN code then I'm trying to output the matched skus as a seperate xml file.

The code I have so far is below, please can you point out where I am going wrong as it's not quite working yet and it's outputting an empty response.

```
$ean = $_GET["ean"];
$trialXML = simplexml_load_file('trial.xml');

//function to lookup an EAN
function lookupEAN($ean,$xml) {

    //loop over products
    foreach($xml->products->product as $product) {
        //loop over individual skus
        foreach($product->sku as $sku) {
            if ($sku->ean == $ean) {  

                $skuData .= $sku;

            }
        }
    }
    return $skuData;
}

//lookup EAN
$response = lookupEAN($ean,$trialXML);

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print_r($response);
```

Thi is an example product from the xml:

```
<product>
        <id>11077810</id>
        <name>Cooke &amp; Lewis Flow Soap Dispenser</name>
        <categoryId>9372170</categoryId>
        <features/>
        <url>http://www.diy.com/diy/jsp/bq/nav.jsp?action=detail&amp;fh_secondid=11077810&amp;fh_location=//catalog01/en_GB/categories&lt;{9372014}/categories&lt;{9372035}/categories&lt;{9372170}/specificationsProductType=bathroom_fittings/specificationsSpecificProductType=soap_dishes___dispensers</url>
        <productHierarchy>
            <productHierarchyElement>Rooms</productHierarchyElement>
            <productHierarchyElement>Bathrooms</productHierarchyElement>
            <productHierarchyElement>Bathroom Accessories</productHierarchyElement>
            <productHierarchyElement>Bathroom Fittings</productHierarchyElement>
            <productHierarchyElement>Soap Dishes &amp; Dispensers</productHierarchyElement>
        </productHierarchy>
        <averageRating>0.0</averageRating>
        <numberOfReviews>0</numberOfReviews>
        <sku>
            <id>11568516</id>
            <name>Cooke &amp; Lewis Flow Soap Dispenser</name>
            <description>From the tradtional to the downright modern, we have accessories to suit the style of your home.  Choose from the classic bronze effect through to the contemporary chrome to add a finishing touch to your bathroom.  Glass and wood enhance some of our bathroom ranges and some have matching toilet seats.</description>
            <ean>0000005286911</ean>
            <price>29.98</price>
            <wasPrice/>
            <deliveryBand>Next day</deliveryBand>
            <deliveryCost>5.0</deliveryCost>
            <deliveryTime>Collect at Store</deliveryTime>
            <deliveryLeadTime>0</deliveryLeadTime>
            <stockAvailability>1</stockAvailability>

            <channel>In Store Only</channel>
            <buyerCats>
                <catLevel0>BATHROOMS</catLevel0>
                <catLevel1>WALL MOUNTED ACCESSORIES</catLevel1>
                <catLevel2>DECO</catLevel2>
            </buyerCats>
            <affiliateCats>
                <affiliateCat0>Home &amp; Garden</affiliateCat0>
            </affiliateCats>
            <categoryHierarchy>Bathroom Fittings</categoryHierarchy>
            <imageUrl>http://s7g1.scene7.com/is/image/BandQ/0000005286911_001c_v001_zp</imageUrl>
            <thumbnailUrl>http://s7g1.scene7.com/is/image/BandQ/0000005286911_001c_v001_zp?$75x75_generic$=</thumbnailUrl>
            <facets>
                <facet name="styleStyle">Flow</facet>
                <facet name="ecoRecycle">false</facet>
                <facet name="specificationsSpecificProductType">Soap Dishes &amp; Dispensers</facet>
                <facet name="ecoGrowFoods">false</facet>
                <facet name="ecoSavesEnergy">false</facet>
                <facet name="ecoNurtureNature">false</facet>
                <facet name="ecoDLME">false</facet>
                <facet name="specificationsProductType">Bathroom Fittings</facet>
                <facet name="featuresBrand">Cooke &amp; Lewis</facet>
                <facet name="ecoHealthyHomes">false</facet>
                <facet name="ecoSavesWater">false</facet>
                <facet name="featuresColour">Chrome</facet>
            </facets>
            <relatedItems>
                                <relatedItem>0000005287512</relatedItem>
                                <relatedItem>0000005287673</relatedItem>
                                <relatedItem>0000005287673</relatedItem>
                            </relatedItems>
            <optionalTags>
                <optionalTag>ROOMS15</optionalTag>
            </optionalTags>
        </sku>
    </product>
```

Comment: see my edit for PHP < 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `simplexml' with`xpath`to select the``node you want - in 3 lines of code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$sku = $xml->xpath("//sku[ean='$ean']")[0]; // select the 1st <sku> node with <ean> = $ean

echo htmlentities($sku->asXML()); // echo or save it as XML
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/F1FR2f

PHP < 5.4, e.g.:

```
$sku = $xml->xpath("//sku[ean='$ean']");
$sku = $sku[0];
```

Comment: I'm using PHP Version 5.2.17 and with this code I get the error message  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in index.php on line X

Comment: @BenPaton: PHP 5.2 is outdated. Upgrade to the current stable PHP 5.4 version and the code just works. If you can not manage that, educate yourself what that method returns and then just port it to PHP 5.2 for example with the *list* language construct: http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath http://php.net/list - You see that syntax error because the code in the answer uses PHP 5.4 array dereferencing: http://php.net/language.types.array